# Rationale for CBOR negative integers

Tags: encoding, signed, cbor

I am confused as to why CBOR chooses to encode negative integers as unsigned binary numbers with the value defined as -1 minus the unsigned value, instead of e.g. regular two's complement representation. Is there an obvious advantage that I'm missing, apart from increased negative range (which, IMO, is of questionable value weighed against increased complexity)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advantages:

1. There's only one allowed encoding type for each integer value, so all encoders will emit consistent output. If the encoders use the shortest encoding for each value as recommended by the spec, they'll emit identical output.
2. Picking the shortest numeric field is easier for non-negative numbers than for signed negative numbers, and CBOR aims for tiny IOT devices to readily transmit data.
3. It fits twice as many values into each integer encoding field width, thus making the data more compact. (It'd be yet more compact if the integer encodings didn't overlap, but that'd be notably more complicated.)
4. It can handle twice as large a negative value before needing the bignum extension.

Comment: Those are all true, though I think 3 & 4 are the main drivers.   For a clever implementation it can reduce size of the decoder, though that may not be clear on first glance.    the "additional information" data is always decoded as unsigned in common code before a decoder dispatches based on Major Type code.

Comment: The disadvantage with CBOR's negative integer format is that the decoded bytes can't be directly memcpy'ed (and endian flipped) into a two's complement signed integer. I don't have any performance tests to determine if the performance penalty is significant, though.

Comment: Why would it be a problem if there are two possible encoding types for a signed integer (like in MessagePack)? Can you provide an example where this is a problem?

Comment: @emilecormier Allowing multiple encodings for the same value has minor costs: less compact encoding, more complicated to test, can't do a generic `cmp` comparison, more bug risk during changes or merges between code forks, ...